# TypeError while representing arbitrary element type in multiprocessing.Array

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, typeerror

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Array, Value
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [(i,[]) for i in range(3)]
>>> a
[(0, []), (1, []), (2, [])]
>>> a[0][1].extend(np.array([1,2,3]))
>>> a[1][1].extend(np.array([4,5]))
>>> a[2][1].extend(np.array([6,7,8]))
>>> a
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 5]), (2, [6, 7, 8])]
```

Following the python multiprocessing [example: def test_sharedvalues():](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) I am trying to create a shared Proxy object using the below code:

```
shared_a = [multiprocessing.Array(id, e) for id, e in a]
```

but it is giving me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 255, in Array
    return Array(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 87, in Array
    obj = RawArray(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 60, in RawArray
    result = _new_value(type_)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 36, in _new_value
    size = ctypes.sizeof(type_)
TypeError: this type has no size
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The problem is solved

I changed

```
>>> a = [(i,[]) for i in range(3)]
```

to

```
>>> a = [('i',[]) for i in range(3)]
```

and this solved the TypeError.

Actually, I also found out that I did not necessarily had to use the i as count within range(3) (since Array automatically allows indexing), The 'i' is for c_int typecode under multiprocessing.sharedctypes

Hope this helps.